# How to write the mathematic formulation of a pairwise sum?

Tags: summation, big-list

In the normal summation, we can do this:

[image]

And that would sum a list X as such in Python:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sum([x_i for i,x_i in enumerate(x)])
10
```

Is there a mathematical symbol for pairwise sum? Like summing the first and second, then second and third, then third and forth? In Python:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
...
>>> x = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> sum([x_i*x_j for x_i,x_j in pairwise(x)])
20
```

Would this math formulation be correct?

[image]

But there's a strange case in the formula above where `i==n` and `i+1` doesn't exist.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_i+x_{i+1})$?

Comment: oooo, yeah how silly of me =)